# Invalid src prop Next.JS S3 and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I am storing images on S3 and using CloudFront to distribute the images.

I have two websites. One is build with Sveltekit and the other with NextJS.

With Svelte, images are loaded fine but with NextJS, I get this "invalid src prop" error.

I add this code in next.config.js and I replaced "example.com" with "cloudfront.net" but didn't work so I tried with "aws.amazon.com" but didn't work either.

What do domain name I have to put and also do I need to add something to pathname as well?

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'example.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the "invalid src prop" error in Next.js when fetching images from S3 via CloudFront, you'll need to configure the next.config.js to recognize your CloudFront domain as a valid domain to load images from. The configuration you're looking for is images.domains.

You can use the following example configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  swcMinify: true,
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['cloudfront.net'],
  },
}
```

In the images configuration:

1. The unoptimized: true setting allows you to use external images
   without the optimization feature of Next.js.
2. The domains array should include any domains you are loading images
   from, including your CloudFront domain ('cloudfront.net').

Remember, it's good practice to be specific with your domains for security reasons. So instead of using the generic 'cloudfront.net', if you have a specific CloudFront URL like 'd12345abcdegh.cloudfront.net', you should use that.